# Не работает spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

не работает spinner. Выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nikita.mozhaev.exchange, PID: 11096
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.nikita.mozhaev.exchange.home.ui.add.AddFragment.onCreateView(AddFragment.java:46)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Вот исходники:
AddFragment.java

```
public class AddFragment extends Fragment {

    String[] data = {"Строительство",
            "Ремонтные работы",
            "Отделочные работы",
            "Сантехнические работы",
            "Электромонтажные работы",
            "Благоустройство территории",
            "Геодезические работы",
            "Теплоснабжение",
            "Охранно-пожарные системы"};


    Spinner prof;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        prof = view.findViewById(R.id.prof);
        prof.setAdapter(adapter);

        prof.setPrompt("Title");

        prof.setSelection(2);

        prof.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас вот тут: `prof = view.findViewById(R.id.prof)` получается `null`. Вы либо ID перепутали либо файл разметки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб   <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/prof"

Comment: Охотно верю. Но это точно в том файле написано, который вы загружаете во фрагмент? Покажите файл разметки `fragment_notifications` для начала.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, это так.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб проблема была в файле. Не на тот ссылался.